# ContextMenuStrip item reference problem

Tags: c#, checked, contextmenustrip

I have searched on here and have not found exactly what I am looking for.

I am using a ContextMenuStrip, within this there is one menu item that is a checked/unchecked item. The structure is the following:

Top Level: Settings
Middle Level: Processing
Bottom Level: Manual processing

I can not find a way to access the Bottom level item, to set it as checked or unchecked.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure I'm following the question. Do you know the name of the "Bottom level item"? If so just reference it by name:

```
bottomLevelMenuItem.Checked = true;
```

If you don't know the name you can loop through the `Items` or `DropDownItems` (depending on the MenuItem type) control collection to find the one you want.

```
foreach (ToolStripMenuItem stripItemCollection in MenuStrip.Items)
{
    ...
}
```

**Edit:**

Correct, [ToolStripItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem_members.aspx) does not have a checked property. It is a base class for many tool strip objects, some of which do not support checking. In this case you are probably dealing with [ToolStripMenuItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripmenuitem_members.aspx)s which do have a checked property.

Try this:

```
ToolStripMenuItem menuItem = this.cmuSystemTray.Items["TLSETTINGS"] as ToolStripMenuItem;
if (menuItem != null)
{
    menuItem.Checked = true;
}
```

Again though each `Control` (`ToolStripMenuItem`) has a name associated with it so it would be easier to use the original variable rather than going through the `Items` property of the context menu strip.

```
TLSETTINGS.Checked = true; // Assuming TLSETTINGS is the name
```

Comment: What I mean is do I do something like the following:

ToolStripItem tItem = this.cmuSystemTray.Items["TLSETTINGS"]

I tried the this.cmuSystemTray.Items["TLSETTINGS"] and .Checked was not a property that I could access

Comment: I apologize that was midleading to you all. Actually TLSETTINGS is the "name" for the top level menu item. The TLMANUAL item is within the TLSETTINGS drop down menu. So I need to reference the LTMANUAL item.

Here is what I have and I am stuck:

ToolStripItem tItem = this.cmuSystemTray.Items["TLSETTINGS"];

From this point I cannot get the lower level items within the iItem 

Can anyone help or direct me to a good example online?

Comment: Ohhhhhh, nevermind I understand what you are talking about now, didn't know that was available to me. That makes it so much easier thank you for your help.